# htaccess changed all the time

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, kohana

I have an htaccess file that keeps getting changed to this

```
## BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
# END WordPress
```

Does anyone know what could be causing this or how do I find out??

Comment: Seems like your wordpress installation is setting the htaccess file.

Comment: It seems logical to think that wordpress does it... have you searched its source?

Comment: do you mean changes are not being saved?

Comment: How is this a *programming* question? http://stackoverflow.com/faq

Comment: I dont have wordpress that is why I find it weird

Comment: Are you using a shared server? Is this your own development machine? Even if you aren't using Wordpress, your machine (if it's shared) maybe set for someone else.

Answer (score 0):

[Wordpress](http://codex.wordpress.org/Using_Permalinks#Fixing_.htaccess_Generation_Issues) writes the .htaccess itself. Follow the steps on that page (but do the opposite of them) to stop it from doing this.

Comment: Hi but I dont have wordpress. I use Kohana